# SAS Array character dates and rename variables after input function

Tags: arrays, sas

Trying to determine a sensible way to clean dates (character), then put those dates in a proper date format via `input` function, but maintain sensible variable names (and possibly even preserve the original variable names) once the char-to-number process is executed.

The dates are being cleaned with an array (replacing `'..'` with `'01'`, or `'....'` with `0101`) since there are about 75 variables that have dates as strings.

Ex. -

```
data sample;
input d1 $ d2 $ d3 $ d4 $ d5 $;
cards;
200103.. 20070905 20060222 2007.... 199801..
;
run;

data clean;
set sample;
array dt_cln(5) d1-d5;
array fl_dt (5) f1-f5;
*clean out '..'/'....', replace with '01'/'0101';
do i=1 to 5;
    if substr(dt_cln(i),5,4) = '....' then do;
        dt_cln(i) = substr(dt_cln(i),1,4) || '0101';
    end;
    else if substr(dt_cln(i),7,2) = '..' then do;
        dt_cln(i) = substr(dt_cln(i),1,6) || '01';
    end;
end;
*change to number;
do i=1 to 5;
    fl_dt(i)=input(dt_cln(i),yymmdd8.);
end;
format f: date9.;
drop i d:;
run;
```

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot preserve the original names and convert from character to numeric directly - however, with a bit of macro code you could drop all the old character variables and rename the numeric versions you've created. E.g.

```
%macro rename_loop();
    %local i;
    %do i = 1 %to 5;
        f&i = d&i
    %end;
%mend;
```

Then in your data step add a rename statement at the end, after your drop statement:

```
rename %rename_loop;
```

Otherwise, your existing approach is already pretty good. You could perhaps simplify the cleaning process a bit, e.g. remove your first do-loop and do the following within the second one:

```
fl_dt(i)=input(tranwrd(dt_cln(i),'..','01'),yymmdd8.);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data want;
   set sample;
   array var1 newd1-newd5;
   array var2  d:;
   do over var2;
      var1=input(ifc(index(var2,'.')^=0,put(prxchange('s/((\.){1,})/0101/',-1,var2),8.),var2),yymmdd8.);
   end;
   format newd1-newd5 yymmddn8.;
   drop d:;
run;
```

Comment: Does that regex work if there is only a single `..` to replace? Also, I would advise against the use of `do over` as that syntax is deprecated.

Comment: it works for both .. and .... with regular expression and put together.